# php get an element's id after submit

Tags: php, html

```
<input type = 'text' name = 'name_'<?php echo $rownum'?>  id = <?php echo $category_id ?> /> $rownum++;
```

After submit I iterate through the text fields. While doing that I want to check whether this text's id is in an array. So for that I want to get the id of the text field. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id`s are not submitted with POST data. It's not possible to get their value back.
Use different `name`s that give you the information you need, since only they are submitted.

Comment: Worked it out by using a hidden field. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

IDs are not accessible with the post. Change it and make it easy to handle

```
<input type = 'text' name = 'name[<?php echo $category_id ?>]'  id = <?php echo $category_id ?> /> $rownum++;
```

Now subimit it and you have everything you want in `$_POST`.

This element will be accessible like this

`$_POST['name']` will be an array iterate through it

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $key => $value)
{
   echo $key; // $key is the id you want
   echo $value; //$value is the value set for this id
}
```

Comment: I already have $rownum as a prefix to the name attribute. So I cannot use that. Maybe I will have to use a hidden field to get the category_id across.

Comment: You could also use a session variable, if you don't want to try and do a hidden input.

Comment: @Pre: May be you can leave `$rownum`  if this can be adjust in your requirement

Comment: Worked it out by using a hidden field. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You would have to specifically pass that value into php.  Once a value is sent out the the browser as HTML php has no more control over it.  So when it gets resubmitted PHP only 'knows' whats handed to it.  In this case it 'know' the name of the input and the value of the input.